# Calculate Average Time from Column B based on Values in Column A

Tags: excel-formula

I'm new to Excel. I'm looking for formula to perform the following.

[image]

Column B has values like TM, LA, Break etc. And Average Handling Time (AHT) will be captured in Column E. Now I need Average AHT for the values in Column B. Ex: If Column B has 6 "TM", then their respective time in Column E should be Averaged. This Avg value will be in Cell G4. Similarly I need Avg AHT time for other values in Column B. Can someone help me in this..

Please Refer to the attached Image above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## AVERAGEIF

Use the [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642).

Place the following formula in G4 and copy to the right:

```
=AVERAGEIF($B$4:$B$15,RIGHT(G$3,2),$E$4:$E$15)
```

Format G4 and H4 to the desired time format or you will see a decimal number.

## Proof of Concept

[image: POC]

## Explanation:

The [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642) has three arguments

```
=AVERAGEIF(A, B, C)
```

- A:  Range of cells that has you criteria in it
- B:  What your criteria is
- C:  Range of cells to take the corresponding average of

In this case A is $B$4:$B$15.  The cell addresses have been lock with the $ to prevent them from changing when the formula is copied.

For B we used the `RIGHT(G$3,2)` formula.  This pulled the last two characters from your header above.  Only rows in B that match the last two characters of the headers will be used for the average calculation.  Alternatively, this could have been hard coded as `"TM"` or `"LA"`

For C, the times in the range $E$4:$E$15 were supplied.  The values that match were added together and then that sum was divided by the number of matches to get the average.